# scipy.convolve gives "ValueError: object too deep for desired array" with 3D array and 3D kernel

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, convolution

I am using Python 3 on Anacona Spyder on CentOS 7.

The following call

```
scipy.convolve(nda, box)
```

gives the following error message.

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

nda and box have the same type and dimensions.

```
np.shape(nda)
Out[51]: (70, 70, 70)

np.shape(box)
Out[52]: (3, 3, 3)

type(nda)
Out[53]: numpy.ndarray

type(box)
Out[54]: numpy.ndarray
```

It is my understanding that scipy.convolve can handles multidimensional objects.  I cannot understand this error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `scipy.convolve` is an alias for [`numpy.convolve`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html), and the NumPy version accepts only one-dimensional input.  (This potential confusion is one of the reasons SciPy is deprecating the use of the NumPy names in the `scipy` namespace.)

You probably want [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html) or [`scipy.signal.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html).  (Why SciPy has independent implementations of  `convolve` in two subpackages is a whole 'nother topic.)

Comment: Or possibly [`scipy.signal.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html)